# Invoke Url to check content type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, request, response

I need to check if the url content type is pdf or not? I have a working code however i was wondering what's the best way to check from what i have. I don't need to display the pdf, just need to check if the content type is pdf or not?
**Note: This method will be called multiple times with different url, so i am not sure if i need to close the response or not.**

here is my code.

```
private bool IsValid(string url)
{
    bool isValid = false;
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && response.ContentType == "application/pdf")
    {
       isValid = true;
    }
    response.Close();
  return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes as you don't pass `response` anywhere you need to dispose it. You should also catch WebException and dispose stream from there too (also I would expect disposing response or even request would close all related resource, but unfortunately I never seen documentation that confirms such cascading dispose behavior for Response object).

You also need to close/dispose the request as it is one-use object. It is specified in note of [GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx):

> Multiple calls to GetResponse return the same response object; the request is not reissued.

Side note: Consider making HEAD request so you don't get any stream at all (see [Method property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method.aspx_) for usage).

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "HEAD";
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting the `HEAD` request, which is particularly relevant in the OP's case.