# Use c# to access and download file from web server using url

Tags: c#

I have two url’s as below (Dummy Examples) which I receive by email.

I want to know if it’s possible to find out using the url which leads to the location of a file like a .pdf or .docx (as I know one does)  and which leads to a homepage of a website (as I know one does).

If one of them does lead to a file location, i want to check the file type, if it’s a .pdf or .docx then i want to download the file.

Can this be done in C#, and if so are there any examples I could follow?

> `http://Test1.TestWebsite.com/dms/fd.php?campaign=441&email=myemail@myDomain.com&user_id=32&id=97`
>
> `http://Test2.TestWebsite.com/dms/fwd.php?campaign=441&email=myemail@myDomain.com&user_id=32&link=40`

Thanks

Comment: Do a web request, check the content-type.

Comment: here is a question with the same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052871/invoke-url-to-check-content-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make a request and check the content type.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SomeUrl);
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.ContentType=="application/pdf"||response.ContentType=="application/ms-word")
            {
                //download the file
            }
        }
```